# Questions about the use of context in clean architecture

Tags: c#, clean-architecture

I have a clean architecture project, but I have an issue.
I make edits and addings new elements on domain model, and it's ok, I guess.
But what about deleting? Because here, I need to have context to remove elements from DB.
Can I pass context to domain model method or will it stop being loosely coupled architecture?

This is part of handle method in Application layer:

```
entity.AddRestaurantTags(tagsChanges.Added);
entity.DeleteRestaurantTags(tagsChanges.Deleted, _context);
entity.EditRestaurantTags(tagsChanges.Edited);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Or I'm doing it wrong, and domain model should be anemic?
I can make it also in handle method, but there is much logic in these methods that repeats many times through system (maybe not in that particular example, but similar)

Comment: which version of entity framework are you using?

Comment: @Jafarashrafi EF6

Comment: don't send context inside entity. while you get entity from database it has tracking on it (unless you use AsNoTracking). while you remove from entity itself, Ef 6 Tracking feature will map it to database.

Comment: but what if I have additional logic to be made inside that method delete? Where I'm not working directly on entity itself but need to check something from _context and I cannot delete thing from entity without doing it. I can check that outside and call method, but it is risky since someone can call it without doing so.

Comment: In these situation sending context and even repository inside domain is prohibited, because it is a code smell. you can use a service to provide data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't pass the dbcontext into your entity. That would mean that your Core Domain project must have a reference to EF, which you don't want as that would add a dependency on an infrastructure/implementation detail.

If you're just deleting stuff, you can simply remove the things from the child collection of the entity and then when you save the entity, the children will removed will be deleted. I think you already get this, I'm just pointing it out for completeness.

But what if you need to do some logic before the deletion, which requires additional data? Well, you have options.

1. Give up on DDD and just put all the logic in a service. Make your entity anemic and give it public mutable properties. Do everything you need in a service. I don't recommend this but it's what many developers end up doing if they can't come up with a better pattern.
2. Pass the data your method needs into it. Whatever data you need the dbContext to go get, just ask for it in your delete method as a parameter. You're deleting a tag on a restaurant, so maybe you're checking if it's the last tag so you can delete the corresponding tag or so you can prevent the delete. So, ask for the currentTagCount as an argument.
3. Use a domain event. If you don't need the dbContext to possibly prevent the operation, but instead to do some follow-up (e.g. after the tag is deleted on the restaurant, if the tag isn't used anywhere, delete its corresponding record), just raise an event. Then in an event handler you can do the follow-up behavior. See my [Clean Architecture template](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture) for an example domain events implementation that would work for this.
4. Pass in an IRepository abstraction.
5. Pass in an IWhatever service abstraction.
6. Pass in a Func or Action.

I look at many different ways to approach this problem (including some of the ones listed above) in this GitHub repo showing how to implement a unique check in an entity:

https://github.com/ardalis/DDD-NoDuplicates

Check it out and let me know if one of those options works for your scenario. If you need more specific guidance it would obviously help to see what your delete method is doing and why it needs a dbContext.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. The variants with passing data and Func are the ones that appeals to me the most, especially the other one. Currently this solves my problems.